After sending a consumption request to iOS, will I still receive a REFUND type webhook?
I have a question.
After receiving a consumption type webhook from iOS, I need to send a consumption request to iOS.
iOS will decide whether to allow or reject the user's refund request. When iOS rejects the user's refund request, will I still receive a REFUND type webhook?
I have now sent a consumption request to iOS, but I want to know how to count whether this request is valid and whether it can help me recover some of the refund losses. Of course, if iOS rejects the user's refund request, I will not receive a REFUND type webhook, which will be simpler.
